# Android intent using direct app open not working in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I tried clicking on Chrome browser version 42 or higher. However, on some devices, the app has not been opened and has been moved to the Google Play Store. Even if the app is installed ...

`<a href="Intent:#Intent;scheme=callMyApp://test?param1=a&param2=b;
          package=com.test.myapp;end"> Click me </a>`

If you try to open the Play Store app in this case, the app will not be able to find any schema parameters. How do I open it without going through the Google Play Store? Or how can I safely pass parameters, whether or not they're open in the Play Store?